# C program shows conflicting type in function in the header file and defined in c file

Tags: c

I am getting a conflicting type error in C but i cant see how there is a conflicting type in the declaration and definition of the same function.

file_utils.h

```
    bool is_relative_path(struct dirent *ent);
```

file_utils.c

```
    bool is_relative_path(struct dirent *ent){
        return (strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") == 0);
    }
```

Error :

```
    abhiram@abhiram-Lenovo-G50-70:~/libpostal-master/src$ gcc -DLIBPOSTAL_DATA_DIR='"$/home/abhiram/libpostal-master/data"' -o main  main.c libpostal.c file_utils.c string_utils.c json_encode.c -std=c99 -w  

    file_utils.c:42:6: error: conflicting types for ‘is_relative_path’
    bool is_relative_path(struct dirent *ent){
         ^
    In file included from file_utils.c:1:0:
    file_utils.h:59:6: note: previous declaration of ‘is_relative_path’ was here
    bool is_relative_path(struct dirent *ent);
         ^
```

The function is declared in the header file and defined in the c file it still shows conflicting type error

Edit: have included dirent.h and stdbool.h in both files.

Comment: Can you please give us the entire compilation command line, because it is truncated.

Comment: @MeherKhiari the compilation command line is not truncated its the entire command . Can you explain what more should i exactly provide ?

Answer (score 2):

The subsequent errors give you the relevant hint: `struct dirent` was only declared, not defined. You need to include the relevant header (`dirent.h`).

In addition, you probably failed to include `stdbool.h` in your header (and included it in your implementation file instead, maybe indirectly).

Comment: Why would they declare that struct locally as an incomplete type though? And that doesn't explain the first 2 errors which might be a missing stdbool.h.

Comment: @Lundin You’re probably right about the missing stdbool.h. I initially considered this but thought maybe some weird declaration causes both problems. But I don’t actually see how this would be possible.

Comment: Dirent was missing in the .c file it resolved the incomplete type error.

Comment: @Abhiram Given the error messages, it’s *definitely* not included. It’s hard to say anything beyond this since you didn’t share the relevant code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes dirent was only included in the header file now its there in both but still not resolving the conflicting type error . Edited the post

Comment: @Abhiram You only need to include it in the header. Inclusion is then transitive (assuming the implementation file includes its corresponding header file).

Comment: @KonradRudolph  Edited the post and included declarations and defination